# Segfault in Linux, works fine on Mac OS

Tags: c++, linux, macos, segmentation-fault

I'm working on a C++ homework assignment in which we have to build a hash table of singly linked lists. I have written my code on a Mac - it compiles fine and generates the expected output perfectly. However, when I run the program in Linux I get segfaults (core dumped). When debugging with gdb, I get the message

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcmp_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S:210
210 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S: No such file or directory.
```

I read on other posted questions on this website that in this case gdb is misleading, and that the problem is not related to the "strcmp" function. However, I'm unable to see where the problem in my code is. If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated. TIA.

```
//string_set.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "string_set.h"

using namespace std;

string_set::string_set() {

    for (int i = 0; i < HASH_TABLE_SIZE; i++) { //initializing empty hash table
        hash_table[i] = NULL;
    } //end for

    iterator_index = 0;
    iterator_node = hash_table[iterator_index];
}

void string_set::add(const char *s) {

    int hash_val = hash_function(s);

    if (contains(s) == 1) {
        throw duplicate_exception();
    } //end if

    node *a = new node;
    if (a==NULL) {
        throw memory_exception();
    } //end if
    a->s = new char[strlen(s) + 1];
    if (a == NULL) {
        delete a;
        throw memory_exception();
    } //end if
    strcpy(a->s, s);

    a->next = hash_table[hash_val];
    hash_table[hash_val] = a;

    if (contains(s) == 0) {
        throw memory_exception();
    } //end if
    else {
        reset();
    } //end else

}

void string_set::remove(const char *s) {

    if (contains(s) == 0) {
        throw not_found_exception();
    } //end if

    int hash_val = hash_function(s);

    node *prev = new node;
    prev = hash_table[hash_val];
    node *ptr = new node;
    ptr = hash_table[hash_val];

    while (strcmp(ptr->s, s) != 0) { // 
        prev = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    } //end while
    if (prev == ptr) { //if node to be deleted is first in list
        hash_table[hash_val] = ptr->next;
    } //end if

    delete ptr->s;
    prev->next = ptr->next;
    delete ptr;

    reset();

}

int string_set::contains(const char *s) {

    int hash_val = hash_function(s);

    node *ptr = new node;
    ptr = hash_table[hash_val];

    while (ptr != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(s, ptr->s) == 0) { // 
            delete ptr;
            return 1;
        } //end if
        else {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        } //end else
    } //end while

    return 0;
}

void string_set::reset() {

    iterator_index = 0;
    iterator_node = hash_table[iterator_index];

}

const char *string_set::next() {

    if (iterator_node != NULL) {
        char copy[strlen(iterator_node->s) + 1];
        strcpy(copy, iterator_node->s);
        iterator_node = iterator_node->next;
        return copy;
    } //end if

    while (iterator_index < HASH_TABLE_SIZE - 1) {
        while (iterator_node == NULL) {
            ++iterator_index;
            iterator_node = hash_table[iterator_index];
            if ((iterator_index == HASH_TABLE_SIZE - 1) && (iterator_node == NULL)) {
                return NULL;
            }
        } //end nested while
        char copy[strlen(iterator_node->s) + 1];
        strcpy(copy, iterator_node->s);
        iterator_node = iterator_node->next;
        return copy;

    } //end while

    return NULL;

}

string_set::~string_set() {

    reset();

    node *ptr = new node;
    ptr = iterator_node;

    while (ptr != NULL) {
        delete ptr->s;
        next();
        ptr = iterator_node;
    } //end while

    delete ptr;
}

int string_set::hash_function(const char *s) {

    int sum = 0;

    for (unsigned int ind = 0; ind < strlen(s); ind++) { //summing elements in string s
        sum += s[ind];
        sum = sum % HASH_TABLE_SIZE;
    } //end for

    return sum % HASH_TABLE_SIZE;
}
```

string_set.h

```
using namespace std;

class string_set {
public:
/*Purpose
    initialize the set to contain no elements
* Preconditions
    none
* Exceptions
    none
*/
string_set();

/*Purpose
*   add s to the set
*   if s is successfully added, reset the iterator
* Preconditions
*   s is a legal string
* Exceptions
*   if s is already present then throw duplicate_exception
*   else if s there is not enough memory to add s then throw memory_exception
*/
void add(const char *s);

/*Purpose
*   remove s from the set
*   if s is successfully removed, reset the iterator
* Preconditions
*   s is a legal string
* Exceptions
*   if s is not present then throw not_found_exception
*/
void remove(const char *s);

/*Purpose
*   return 1 if s is in the set and 0 otherwise
* Preconditions
*   s is a legal string
* Exceptions
*   none
*/
int contains(const char *s);

/*Purpose
*   reset the iterator to the first element
* Preconditions
*   none
* Exceptions
*   none
*/
void reset();

/*Purpose
*   return a pointer to the next set element
*   return NULL if no more elements remain
* Preconditions
*   none
* Exceptions
*   none
*/
const char *next();

/*Purpose
*   delete all dynamically allocated memory
* Preconditions
*   none
* Exceptions
*   none
*/
~string_set();
private:
/*Purpose
*   return the hash value h associated with s
*   h must consist of: (sum of the characters in s) mod HASH_TABLE_SIZE
* Preconditions
*   s is a legal string
* Exceptions
*   none
* Examples
*   hash_function("a") returns 97
*   hash_function("ab") returns 95
*   hash_function("ba") returns 95
*   hash_function("") returns 0
*/
int hash_function(const char *s);

enum {HASH_TABLE_SIZE = 100};

class node {
    public:
    char *s;
    node *next;
};

// hash_table[i] is the head of a linked list of nodes
node *hash_table[HASH_TABLE_SIZE];

// iterator position
int iterator_index; // index in hash_table
node *iterator_node; // node in hash_table[iterator_index];
};

class duplicate_exception { };
class memory_exception { };
class not_found_exception { };
```

Comment: There are a number of things that are dodgy about this code (classes with pointer members and no rule of 0/3/5, variable length arrays, raw memory allocation), but perhaps the one causing your issue is the fact that `string_set::next()` returns a pointer to a local array (`copy`). There are also a number of obvious memory leaks (`node *prev = new node`, `node *ptr = new node` etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your help! Sorry, I'm not familiar with the rule of 0/3/5?

Comment: The `delete ptr;` in contains doesn't help any, either, and could be the cause of your segfault.  While you allocate a new node for ptr, you then overwrite that with `hash_table[hash_val]`, and delete data you still point to while leaking the original allocation.

Comment: Lots of problems with the code as previous commenter has stated. Another problem directly related to your question is in `remove`: `while (strcmp(ptr->s, s) != 0) { `. You need to check whether `ptr` is NULL before doing the compare.

Comment: @anon http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does anyone know why my code posted above would work fine on one operating system but not another?

Answer (score 0):

These lines of code in your `contains` function:

```
   if (strcmp(s, ptr->s) == 0) { // 
        delete ptr;
```

will delete the memory for the node you just found, causing undefined behaviour when you then try to use that node later on.

In several places in your code, you a allocating a new node for a pointer, then immediately pointing the pointer to a different location - this will cause memory leaks and is possibly leading you to delete thing you did not mean to.

```
node *ptr = new node;
ptr = hash_table[hash_val];
```

should be

```
node *ptr = hash_table[hash_val];
```

and then there is no need for a corresponding `delete` (unless you are actually removing the node).

Comment: Thank you! RE: 
    node *ptr = new node;
    ptr = hash_table[hash_val];

shouldn't have listened to my prof after all...